# javascript - invoke polymorphic method of object that was read from storage.StorageArea

Tags: javascript, polymorphism, prototype, storage

I have prototype `A` with method `m()` and two its heirs: `B` and `C`, each of which has overrided `m()`. Many objects of `A`, `B` and `C` are stored in array `arr`. I can save this array to [storage.StorageArea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea) or load it from there. But after loading it seems like objects inside gotten array are not instances of `A`, `B` or `C`, but just sets of properties without methods. In this way `arr[i].m()` leads to

> TypeError: arr[i].m is not a function

I could use `A.prototype.m.call(arr[i])` but where does polymorphism? What is the efficient way?

**Edit: some code added**

```
var A = function(name) {
    this.name = name
}
A.prototype.m = function() {
    console.log("I am " + this.name);
}

var B = function(name) {
    A.apply(this, [name]);
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

var C = function(name) {
    A.apply(this, [name]);
}
C.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
C.prototype.constructor = C;

function main() {
    let arr = new Array(3);
    arr[0] = new A("A");
    arr[1] = new B("B");
    arr[2] = new C("C");

    console.log("-- before storing --");
    arr[0].m();
    arr[1].m();
    arr[2].m();

    browser.storage.local.set({arr});
    browser.storage.local.get({arr}).then(onSuccess);
}

function onSuccess(result) {
    console.log("Result: ");
    console.log(result);
    console.log("-- after storing --"); 
    result.arr[0].m();
    result.arr[1].m();
    result.arr[2].m();
}
```

Comment: add some code please.

Comment: @SaikatHajra done

Comment: `browser.storage.local` does not work. which browser you are using

Comment: @SaikatHajra Mozilla Firefox, `storage` permission is required. It's need to make some effort to run code. Here is console output (I added `console.log(arr)` after `console.log("-- before storing --")` line): https://i.imgur.com/KQ35RLq.png

Comment: @SaikatHajra as I got, my objects become not an instances of `A`, `B` or `C`, but just instances of `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `browser.storage.local.set` the provided object get `stringified` first then it gets stored.

Now when you trying to get back the value its get `JSON.parse`.

Now here as you know `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(anyobject))` will return a completely clone object which has no link with the **anyobject**. They both have different references. That's the reason why you are experiencing such result.

In general I mostly use `window.localStorage.setItem` and I need to explicitly pass the `stringified` value and after fetching the value I `parse` it back to get the object.

Comment: I not really understood your advice. Should I use `window.localStorage.setItem` instead of `browser.storage.local.set` or after `browser.storage.local.get`? And where is linking of gotten object to its prototype?

Comment: No I did not advise you to use `window.localStorage.seItem`. I mentioned what is happening behind the scene and why you are getting a completely new object rather than an object of `A` `B` or `C`

Comment: Oh I long understood this, but understanding didn't solve the problem so I'm here

Comment: I don't think there is any way to get back the same object with the same reference if you are storing in `localStorage`.